# Count Dates which a specific Customer does not have a Shop in it

Tags: c#, linq

Here is an example Data Table:

```
ID    Amount     Date
--------------------------
1      3.000     2016/1/1
2      4.000     2016/1/1
1      6.000     2017/1/1
1      3.000     2018/1/1
3      2.000     2019/1/1
```

I need to count Dates which a specific Customers does not have a Shop in it.
for example `ID 2` does not have a shop in `2017/1/1` and `2018/1/1`, so the count will be `2`. and the count for customer `ID 3` will be `3` because He does not have a shop in `2016/1/1` and `2017/1/1` and `2018/1/1`

I think I should use grouping but do not know how to count which I want for a specific ID!

```
orders.GroupBy(x => x.Date)......???
```

Comment: What stopped you on a half way solving this task? Any code from your side? Names of variables maybe?

Comment: I'm mixed up with grouping. I think I should group by date but do not know how to count a specific `ID` which does not exists in that specific date

Comment: And which dates do count? Only the ones with other customer rows?

Comment: Not quite sure if I got your question right. Do you mean something like `orders.GroupBy(x => x.Date).Count(x => !x.Any(y => y.ID == yourUserId));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have list of objects:

```
// number of all different dates
var datesCount = list.Select(i => i.Date).Distinct().Count(); 

int customerId = 2;

//number of dates with customer shopping
var customerDatesCount = list.Where(i => i.ID == customerId).Select(i => i.Date).Distinct().Count();

var nonShoppingDatesCount = datesCount - customerDatesCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need two steps here.

1. Get all distinct order dates

   `var allDates = orders.Select(o => o.Date).Distinct();`
2. Find those dates which customer don't have. `Except` operation will do that

   `var missingDates = allDates.Except(orders.Where(o => o.ID == 2).Select(o => o.Date));`

If you need just number of missing dates, then use `missingDates.Count()` or (better) use solution by @Roma

Comment: Thank you man, it is working, but the Roma's code is 3 times faster. :)

Comment: @Stranger yep, I just missed the part where you said only count is needed. If you'll need missing date values, you will know how to get them :)